# What happens to blocked system calls on receiving signal?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, signals, interrupt

Assume that a linux process is trying to read() data from a socket and is blocked on socked fd. What happens to this when it is interrupted by a signal ?
Will it return with errno EINRPT or continue to read() on socket fd ?

Is there any generic rule that applies to all the system calls on reception of signals ?

Comment: [man 7 signal](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Section: "Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers".

Comment: And there are also similar questions/answers on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049756/when-and-how-are-system-calls-interrupted

Answer (score 3):

In the specific case of sockets, `read(2)` is considered to be a slow syscall because it can block forever; therefore if a signal is received for which a signal handler has been set up, one of two things can happen:

1. If the signal handler was set with the `SA_RESTART` flag in the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction`, then the syscall is automatically restarted after (and if) the handler returns (cases where the handler does not return include, but are not limited to, handler code that calls `exit(3)` or uses `longjmp(3)` / `setjmp(3)`); user code does not see `EINTR` in this case.
2. If the `SA_RESTART` flag was not set, the syscall returns prematurely and `errno` is set to `EINTR`.

For the generic rules, see `man 7 signal`, pay particular attention to the section *Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers*