# Is AF_UNIX socket send thread safe?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, sockets

Looked around, but could not find any link justifying the answer for AF_UNIX sockets.

My implementation is on a linux system, I have an AF_UNIX SOCK_STREAM socket,

- one receiver thread on this socket
- few worker threads which can call 'send()' on this socket.

My question is - **are AF_UNIX socket 'send()' thread safe? If I have threads parallely/concurrently calling send on the AF_UNIX socket fd, will kernel take care of the synchronization?**

I went through multiple links, but all are related to TCP/UDP (AF_INET) sockets, so if anyone could suggest a link that justifies the answer, or could provide some insight into the kernel code, it would be of great help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with threads.

Answer (score 6):

[POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html) that all functions it defines must be thread-safe, except those on a list of specific exceptions.  The `send(2)` function is defined by POSIX and is not included on the list of exceptions.  Inasmuch as the Linux implementation of `send(2)` purports to conform to POSIX specifications, you can rely on it to be thread-safe.

Comment: As far as I know, "Linux" is not a "POSIX-compliant system".

Comment: @Rhymoid, `send()` is a syscall, and its Linux implementation in is documented to conform to POSIX.  I have updated my answer to be more precise in that regard.

Comment: Yes but what does "thread safe" mean?

Comment: @curiousguy, as far as POSIX is concerned, a function being thread-safe means that if that function is called concurrently by two different threads, then the behavior of each call is consistent with the specifications for the function.

Answer (score 1):

In general, operations like read or write are atomic. But on pipes or sockets things are different.

For **pipes**, POSIX, but I suspect Linux to be compliant on that point, states that concurrent writes are guaranteed not be interleaved only if length is less than `PIPE_BUF`. See [POSIX write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html).

For **sockets**, Linux manual for `send` family functions says:

> When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket,
>          send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in
>          nonblocking I/O mode.

This suggests that the kernel probably `send`s your message into pieces, just like with pipe semantic.

There exists a provided answer on this subject [Is send atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041171/is-a-successful-send-atomic).